# org-capture fails: base buffer has been killed

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I am trying to set up [GTD for org-mode by Nicolas Petton](https://emacs.cafe/emacs/orgmode/gtd/2017/06/30/orgmode-gtd.html). I have a very simple org-capture-template:

```
(setq org-capture-templates '(("t" "Todo [inbox]" entry
                               (file+headline "~/org/gtd/inbox.org" "Inbox")
                               "* TODO %i%?")))
```

Whenever I want to capture something, first *Org-Select* buffer opens and when I select the template, the buffer closes and it gives me the message `Capture template 't': Base buffer has been killed`.

There is nothing wrong with the template but I couldn't figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, I updated the package `org` from version 8.X.X to the version 9.2.3 and the problem was solved.